# rspec: ignoring format while testing a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing test for my views. I happen to have html and json views for one action, and I didn't figured out how can I force rspec to use a given format.

Currently I minimized my code to the following:

```
# cat spec/views/services/index.json.jbuilder_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "services/index" do
  let(:services) { 3.times.map { FactoryGirl.create(:service) } }
  before(:each) { assign(:services, services) }
  let(:resp) do
      render template: 'services/index', format: :json # note the format here
      JSON.parse(response.body, simbolize_names: true)
    end

  it("should be an array") { resp.should be_kind_of(Array) }
end
```

but it stills rendering the HTML code. I'm getting the error

```
Failure/Error: JSON.parse(response.body, simbolize_names: true)
JSON::ParserError:
757: unexpected token at '<h1>Listing services</h1>
[cut rest of HTML]
```

My json view is very simple

```
# cat app/views/services/index.json.jbuilder
json.array! @services, *Service.json_attributes
```

And the first 5 lines of my html view is

```
# cat app/views/services/index.html.haml  | head -5
%h1 Listing services

%table
  %tr
    %th Logo
```

If I try to pass the format in the render template, like

```
render template: 'services/index.json'
```

I got the following:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a template handler in the template name is
deprecated. You can simply remove the handler name or pass render
```

My rspec is version 2.13.1, running on ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just curious:
Does `render template: 'services/index', formats: :json` work well?
Notice **formats** with **s** in the end.

Comment: omg, thank you! Any idea why "formats" if a template can only have one?

Comment: Please, see the following conversation https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4841.